# Parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having two view pages using the same controller and model as a way to change the page layout but i am having trouble displaying my second page. This is my error message: `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter id of non-nullable type for method system.web.mvc.actionaresult ListView(int32) in UserController`

Not sure what is causing the problem i used the same code for the first view page(working) except just changing the view layout.

**First View**

```
<div>
<a href="/Roster/ListView">Click Here for List view</a>
</div>

<section id="users" data-bind="foreach: Users">
    <div id="nameImage">
        <figure id="content">
            <img width="158" height="158" alt="Gravatar" data-bind="attr:{src: GravatarUrl}"/>
            <figcaption>
                <a title="Email" id="emailIcon" class="icon-envelope icon-white" data-bind="attr:{'href':'mailto:' + Email()}"></a>
                <a title="Profile" id="profileIcon" class="icon-user icon-white"></a>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p data-bind="text:Name"></p>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

**List View**

```
<div class="accordion-inner">
<div data-bind="foreach: Users">
    <div>
        <img width="158" height="158" alt="Gravatar" data-bind="attr:{src: GravatarUrl}"/>
        <p data-bind="text:Name"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult View(int id)
    {
        // get the menu from the cache, by Id
        ViewBag.SideBarMenu = SideMenuManager.GetRootMenu(id);
        ViewBag.UserApiURL = "/api/User/" + id.ToString();
        return View(); 
    }

    public ActionResult ListView(int id)
    {
        // get the menu from the cache, by Id
        ViewBag.SideBarMenu = SideMenuManager.GetRootMenu(id);
        ViewBag.UserApiURL = "/api/User/" + id.ToString();
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Api controller**

```
private UserService _userService = new UserService();

    public IEnumerable<User> Get(int? id)
    {
        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            return _userService.GetUsers(id.Value);
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL `/Roster/ListView` is missing an ID value. You'll need to either:

1. Change the URL to something like `/Roster/ListView/123`
2. Change the action method to allow a nullable integer by changing the type from `int` to `int?`. Then in the action method you need to check if the `id` parameter is null or not and deal with that appropriately, such as by returning an error, or just ignoring the id.

Comment: but shouldn't the `+ id.ToString()` should add the parameter?

Comment: @Amina the error is coming from the call to the MVC controller, not the Web API controller. The MVC controller action cannot even be called. So the error isn't coming from *within* the controller, it's coming before the controller action method is even run.

Comment: ok i see that now. I changed it and know it is throwing an error saying that `doesn't contain a definition for "UserApiURL"` the `ViewBag` i have. even though it is in the controller

Answer (score 2):

You write following link `href="/Roster/ListView"` but action **ListView** require `parameter id`, which is missing here.

Comment: I hard coded in `href="/Roster/ListView/9"` but still not showing

Comment: Try to use @Html.ActionLink mvc helper for generating proper link

Comment: Nice job Garath on using an action link to display what should be there.  That helped me fix an issue I was having.  Thanks